# To Calculate average of numbers put in HTML table by user using OnClick()

Tags: javascript, html

Currently having problems identifying an error I have in my HTML/JavaScript code which is preventing my JavaScript function calculating the average of five numbers which is put in by the user of the table.

Nothing happens when I click "Calculate Grade" after I put in numbers into the required cells. Struggling to see the problem.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows = table.rows;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var cells = rows[i].cells;
  var sum = 0;
  for (var x = 0; x < cells.length; x++) {
    var cell = cells[x];
    sum += parseInt(cell.innerHTML);
  }
  var average = sum / cells.length;
  rows[i].innerHTML += "<td>" + average + "</td>";
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th id="StudentName" bgcolor="FFF55A">Name</th>
    <th id="IDnumber" bgcolor="#FFF55A">ID</th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFF55A">Assignment 1</th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFF55A">Assignment 2</th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFF55A">Assignment 3</th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFF55A">Assignment 4</th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFF55A">Assignment 5</th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFF55A">Final</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'>Person1 </td>
    <td>1546396</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'>Person2</td>
    <td contenteditable='false'>45942544</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'>Person3</td>
    <td contenteditable='false'>48498465</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'> Person4</td>
    <td contenteditable='false'>4964984</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'>Person5</td>
    <td contenteditable='false'> 5686846</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'>Person6</td>
    <td contenteditable='false'>498465</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'>Person7</td>
    <td contenteditable='false'>654684</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'>Person8</td>
    <td contenteditable='false'>6498497</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'>Person9</td>
    <td contenteditable='false'>8749846</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>2</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>45</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>57</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>2</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='false'>Person10</td>
    <td contenteditable='false'>984894</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="button1">Calculate grade</button>
```

Comment: the script wont work on jsfiddle becuse it's placed inside the head section while the dom element is not yet ready

Comment: Remember to vote for any answer if your problem has been solved

Comment: Yes KARC i will, I am still looking at domink's extra functionality he added trying to understand it, i will vote soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited yout fiddle a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/StarStep/m7v1j5zz/105/
and added an event listner on the calculate button:
`<button id="myFunction" class="button1">Calculate grade</button>`

```
function myFunction() {
   var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   var rows = table.rows;

   for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
     var cells = rows[i].cells;
     var sum = 0;
         var numbers = 0;
     for (var x = 2; x < (cells.length -1); x++) {
       var cell = cells[x];
       var addme = parseInt(cell.innerHTML);
       if(!isNaN(addme)) {       
          sum += addme;
          numbers++;
       }
     }
     var average = sum / numbers;
     rows[i].cells[7].innerHTML = "<td>" + Math.round(average) + "</td>";
   }
 }

document.getElementById('myFunction').onclick = myFunction;
```

Comment: I can explain if you do not understand something

Comment: To my second for loop i see you have added an addition if statement and var called addme. So you are setting what the user puts into the cell in the table equal to addme. Then the if statement is saying if what was entered into the cell is a number do, sum+= addme and increment numbers. Correct?

Comment: also i see you fixed another problem i had too where if where you click "calculate grade" twice for example it would create two new columns, you fixed that in the second for loop by saying cells.length-1, while i just had  cells.length, could you explain the reasoning why this works? thanks

Comment: Yes, i just replaced the last element in the columns whith the result, instead of "rows[i].innerHTML +=" to prevent duplicates. And the "cells.length -1" is needed to remove the last column ("final") from the sum loop :D

Answer (score 1):

Place the JavaScript in `<head>` tag. You cannot place `myFunction` after the `onclick`. This will work if you want to use inline script declare script before `onclick`.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
 var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows=table.rows;

for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++){
 var cells = rows[i].cells;
 var sum = 0;

 for(var x = 2; x < cells.length; x++){
  var cell = cells[x];
  sum += parseInt(cell.innerHTML);
 }
 var average = sum/cells.length;
 rows[i].innerHTML += "<td>"+Math.round(average)+"</td>";
}
}
</script>

<button  onclick="myFunction()" class="button1">Calculate grade</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are four main problems in your script:

1. If a user enters empty string or string that is not convertable to a `Number`, you're adding `NaN` to your `sum`. And even if user enters four assignment correctly but the first one is incorrect, the result is `NaN` because `NaN + 1 + 2 = NaN`
2. While calculating the average, you're dividing the sum by the length of **all** of the cells. And the first two cells (`name`, `ID`) shoudn't be counted.
3. I believe that if a user omits some assignment, your script should calculate the average correctly anyway. So if there are only three assignment entered, your divisor (`cells.length` in your current version) also should be equal to `3` to calculate the average correctly.
4. Finally, but less importantly, I think that if a user doesn't enter any assignment, the average should be 0, not `NaN`.

I edited your script with the changes above:

```
function myFunction() {

  var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
  var rows=table.rows;

  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].cells;
    var sum = 0;
    var cellsLength = cells.length - 2; // the first two cells shouldn't be counted 
    for (var x = 2; x < cells.length; x++) {
      var cell = cells[x];
      var toAdd = Number(cells[x].innerHTML) ? Number(cells[x].innerHTML) : 0; // prevent adding NaN
      sum += toAdd;
      if (!Number(cells[x].innerHTML)) {
        cellsLength--; // if the value is invalid, it shouldn;t be counted while calculating the average
      }
    }
    var average = sum/cellsLength || 0; // calculate the average, but if it's undefined or NaN, replace it with 0
    rows[i].innerHTML += "<td>" + Math.round(average) + "</td>";
  }
}
```

Feel free to check out updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m7v1j5zz/110/